# Model the constraint ‘Only if decision 1 is yes and decision 2 is no, then decision 3 is allowed to be yes’

Tags: mathematical-modeling, binary, constraints, binary-programming

Model the constraint ‘Only if decision 1 is yes and decision 2 is no, then decision 3 is allowed to be yes’ as a set of linear constraints that should simultaneously be satisfied. Add binary variable(s) where needed.

[Image Of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so6en.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you got any ideas?

Comment: Hint: If $ a, b \in \{0,1\}$, then $ ab = 1 $ iff $a=1, b=1$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Via conjunctive normal form:
$$
y_3 \implies (y_1 \land \lnot y_2) \\
\lnot y_3 \lor (y_1 \land \lnot y_2) \\
(\lnot y_3 \lor y_1) \land (\lnot y_3 \lor \lnot y_2) \\
(1- y_3 + y_1 \ge 1) \land (1- y_3 + 1- y_2 \ge 1) \\
(y_3 \le y_1) \land (y_3 \le 1 - y_2) \\
$$